# Type reduce in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

```
const field: Array<{x: number, y: number}> = columns.reduce((array, y) => {
    rows.map(x => array.push({x: x, y: y})) //Error:(20, 39) TS2322: Type 'number' is not                                    
                                            //assignable to type never
    return array
}, [])
```

How to solve this type error I'm having?

Comment: What is the type of `columns`?

Comment: And where does `rows` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `columns` and `rows` have type `number[]`, you can either specify the type of the empty array passed as second parameter of `reduce` like this:

```js
const field = columns.reduce((array, y) => {
  rows.map(x => array.push({ x: x, y: y }))
  return array
}, [] as Array<{ x: number, y: number }>)
```

Or pass the type parameter to `reduce` like that:

```js
const field = columns.reduce<Array<{ x: number, y: number }>>((array, y) => {
  rows.map(x => array.push({ x: x, y: y }))
  return array
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initialiser for the `reduce` method is currently an empty array `[]`.

Set that initial value to have the correct type:

```
type coordinatesType = Array<{ x: number, y: number }>

const field = columns.reduce((array, y) => {
  rows.forEach(x => array.push({ x: x, y: y }))
  return array
}, [] as coordinatesType)
```

Or give that type to the `reduce`

```
type coordinatesType = Array<{ x: number, y: number }>

const field = columns.reduce<coordinatesType>((array, y) => {
  rows.forEach(x => array.push({ x: x, y: y }))
  return array
}, [])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=26&pln=3&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2BXAtpGBeGBtAjAGhgCYCBmAXQFgAoUSWAJxAHcINt8jTKrqoBPAA4BTOCBD0AJgEswAQyhCIAFUEjMAQXr1ZfADwBvGAA8AXDDAoARkPoE%20Zi8mv0YAXwB81arWgwAZlJC8BJsCCiQAHT0QhKIwEIAFAmyWjp2AJQY7jD61DAwjCwRfuIAorLAABYJRlkwKdp8EQKIENWGpsZ2Znxu6el5BUJQiPRg9al81K4EWGT1rKDi0nIKyqoDPDTgECDwQhHwIADmCQFBEulAA)

Answer (score 0):

The good way for using `reduce` is `columns.reduce<Array<{ x: number, y: number }>>`. However, I would not use `reduce` in this case, but `flatMap` if ES2019 is supported:

```js
const field = columns.flatMap(y => rows.map(x => ({ x, y })));
```